pm2 frontend process restarts how to debug
We have a server running on CENTOS and as stack we use VUE3 with Nodejs, NUXT and EXPRESS js
Pm2 is also used for process management
The server has been running for a couple of years but lately we've been having issues that the PM2 frontend process has been restarting frequently out of its own.

In this image we can see the frontend process restarts of its own as it has a lower uptime than all the other processes which got restarted with a code deploy.
We have checked for memory leaks and fixed a lot of individual issues in our codebase but the memory usage is always between 1 and 2,5 GB (pm2 list / monit) it will never go higher than 2.5GB and in the ecosystem.config we have specified:
max_memory_restart: '8G'
node_args: '--max-old-space-size=8096 --openssl-legacy-provider',

So we don't understand why the restarts still happen.
If it would be a real memory leak we would expect the memory to climb till the 8GB treshhold and then crash/reset.
At this moment we have spent a lot of time already and are getting out of ideas where to look/debug for possible causes.
There are no error logs, the output logs look fine and have nothing dodgy. So I'm not sure what is causing this.
Does anyone have any idea of what could be a possible cause or other paths we should check/explore and how?
Could there be other processes apart from pm2 choking the server that we are missing?
